# commenting out python code including comments in it

Tags: python, unit-testing, comments, multiline

Imagine this situation.

I am unittesting a piece of code and in order to do that I passed a multiline string to a class.
I have several methods to test:

```
def testMyClassmethod2(self):
   print('\n>>Start 2')
   comment= '\n two references no brakets\n'
        
   desc = '''This is a multiline text
        including another line,
        and yet another'''
```

Now imagine I have 20 methods. I made a buch of changes and when I run the unittest I get a bunch of errors.
I would like to go one by one looking at what is going on. (Yes, it might not be the best design approach, the unittests should passed)
In any case I would like to comment out all the methods from method 1 on.
OK, my idea was using ''' before method 2 and ''' at the end before if **name**='main', but this does not work since every method containes a multiline string already using ''' x x x '''.

How do you proceed? Is there a way to include also those strings in a commented out code?

NOTE: I am working in VS code

Comment: Why not just comment out with `#`? Most editors will have quick keyboards shortcuts to comment & uncomment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with a swiss keyboard

CTRL + /  (but in numpad keys) does the job.

in a swiss keyboard using "/" as in MAYS+7 does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your specific editor, but on most just highlight the code and press `Ctrl` + `/`.

**EDIT:** For Visual Studio Code that is also the command (https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)